# topological invariance of being contained in a set of given dimension

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $U$ is contained in $E^n$ ($n$-dimensional Euclidean space) and is homeomorphic to a set $V$ in $E^m$, where $m>n$.  Is there a topological manifold in $E^m$ of dimension $n$ that contains $V$?

Comment: Probably not. Let $C$ be a Cantor set, then $C^k$ is homeomorphic to $C$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, and I don't think you can find an $n$-dimensional topological manifold $M$ with $C^m \subset M \subset E^m$.

Answer (score 0):

No since $\mathbb{Q} $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q} $ and $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q} $ is not contained in any one dimensional topological  manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2.$